# Terraform: How to check the "Use Lambda Proxy integration" check box selected with Terraform in GET - Integration Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway

[image]I have created the AWS API gateway with terraform.
But I can't figure out how to select the Lambda Proxy integration checkbox selected with my terraform.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "request_method_get" {
  rest_api_id   = local.rest_api_id
  resource_id   = local.resource_id
  http_method   = "GET"
  authorization  = "CUSTOM"
  authorizer_id = aws_api_gateway_authorizer.auth.id
  
}
```

I tried to include `request_parameters = { "method.request.querystring.some-query-param" = true }`

But it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is set using [aws_api_gateway_integration](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration) with type of `AWS_PROXY`. Check examples given in the docs.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm using OpenAPI spec with `x-amazon-apigateway-integration`, but had the `type` set to `aws` rather than `aws_proxy`.